# run windows nt's cmd or bat files on linux

Tags: windows, bash, shell, cmd

If I want to run bash scripts on Windows, I can install cygwin.
But, I want to run .bat-files on Linux. Are there such shell ( port of cmd.exe:) ) under linux ?

Comment: I don't know of one, but you might want to look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463212.aspx. I may have missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to run .bat files on linux, if you really want to do that, you can use WINE on linux.
The CMD language does not have a lot of programming constructs and rarely used to do anything complicated, they are very windows specific and mainly used to start up other programs on windows.

There is a relatively simple way to wrap bash scripts in .bat though.

```
@setlocal
@cd C:\cygwin\bin
@start bash --login -i /home/your_id/yourscript
@endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation what I don't want:)
I want to run .cmd/.bat because I have some very simple "program starters", like this:

rc/run_smth param1 param2 $*

They are in user's work folder. I want to make them easily accessible from Windows's console and Linux. I see 3 ways for it: 1)shell scrypts+cygwin 2)<subject of my question> 3)to write this "starters" on Python (looks to heavy tool for such simple one-liners).
As most of my users use Windows now, I prefer to make life simpler for them. Actually, the only Linux user now is me:)) Sorry I don't explain it from the start.